# Getting coordinates explicitly from GPS provider

Tags: android, gps

I want to achieve something which I though was simple enough, but now I end up being a little confused.
I want to get the coordinates of the user in this way

- Is there a GPS provider?

  - If yes, get the coordinates from gps
  - Else if there is a network provider get them from there

I used both `locationManager` and `onLocationChange()`, and the new API with `locationClient` but I can't get the coordinates from my device's GPS, only from network.

This is the one with the `locationManager`

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use default
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

// Initialize the location fields
if (location != null) {
    System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
    // new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).setMessage("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.").show();
    onLocationChanged(location);   
    System.out.println(location.getLatitude());
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DriveMeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("monument", monument);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", location.getLatitude());
    intent.putExtra("longitude",location.getLongitude());
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(con).setMessage("Location not available").show();
    System.out.println("Location not available");
    System.out.println("Location not available");
}
```

and this is the one with `locationClient`

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(v.getContext())
if(mLocationClient.getLastLocation()!=null)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+ "|" + 
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude() ,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: You need to show more code. Somehow your "is there a GPS provider" request is getting "no" even though you believe it should be "yes". Perhaps your application is not allowed access to location services (privacy?).

Comment: Ok i'll post the code now. I have all necessary permissions in the manifest, also I'checked if there was  a gps provider available and it was but it return the location as null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16393534/2345913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's the complete code to find the best available provider whether `gps` or `network` and show `settings menu` to enable the `location services`.

```
    public class DSLVFragmentClicks extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private final int BESTAVAILABLEPROVIDERCODE = 1;
private final int BESTPROVIDERCODE = 2;
LocationManager locationManager;
String bestProvider;
String bestAvailableProvider;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == BESTPROVIDERCODE) {
        if (requestCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(bestProvider)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! Location Service " + bestProvider + " not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            getLocation(bestProvider);
        }
    } else {
        if (requestCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(bestAvailableProvider)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! Location Service " + bestAvailableProvider + " not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            getLocation(bestAvailableProvider);
        }
    }
}

public void getLocation(String usedLocationService) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "getting Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    long updateTime = 0;
    float updateDistance = 0;
    // finding the current location 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(usedLocationService, updateTime, updateDistance, this);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // set a Criteria specifying things you want from a particular Location Service
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // finding best provider without fulfilling the criteria
            bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            // finding best provider which fulfills the criteria
            bestAvailableProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            String toastMessage = null;
            if (bestProvider == null) {
                toastMessage = "NO best Provider Found";
            } else if (bestAvailableProvider != null && bestAvailableProvider.equals(bestAvailableProvider)) {
                boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(bestAvailableProvider);
                if (!enabled) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Please enable " + bestAvailableProvider + " to find your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
// show settings menu to start gps or network location service
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(mainIntent, BESTAVAILABLEPROVIDERCODE);
                } else {
                    getLocation(bestAvailableProvider);
                }
                toastMessage = bestAvailableProvider + " used for getting your current location";
            } else {
                boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(bestProvider);
                if (!enabled) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Please enable " + bestProvider + " to find your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(mainIntent, BESTPROVIDERCODE);
                } else {
                    getLocation(bestProvider);
                }
                toastMessage = bestProvider + " is used to get your current location";

            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("Location Found", location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
    // getting the street address from longitute and latitude
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    String addressString = "not found !!";
    try {
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (addressList.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                stringBuilder.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                stringBuilder.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                stringBuilder.append(address.getCountryName()).append("\n");
            }

            addressString = stringBuilder.toString();
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Your Location is " + addressString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
}
```

I have already explained a lot in comments but if you still don't understand something then feel free to ask.

Comment: GPS may take sometime to get a lock of your location. You can use the network to check whether you are getting any coordinates or not. You may use log to post a log when gps gets a location. This way you will know that you received a location even if it takes sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are trying it on a device and you have tried it out in open. In most cases You won't get gps coordinates until you step out.

Comment: no, I'm not in the open...I'm in an office, could that be the problem?

Comment: yes definitely.. just go to terrace or step out in open and check if you get any reading and let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you don't have the location fix and GPS locationProvider takes time to get the location fix in compare to network location provider.

What can you do is that you can use the last known location fix.

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
// Or use LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
```

But the further problem is that you might have the old location fix and network provider can provide you better location.

Android has really good documentation on this and sample code to find the best known location. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: I suspect if GPS provider is being used recently in your device. Could you go out and try to get the GPS fix at least once (by using another app- google maps or any other app), and then try the code again.

Comment: My cell is new, but it's a used one and i restored it to factory setting. If it helps you, google maps won't also work when I have only gps activated

Comment: yeah, that's the exact problem. It's not surprising if GPS takes hour to get the gps fix or even if it couldnt get the fix due to bad weather. I would recommend you to try for few minutes (10-20 min) for GPS fix otherwise there might be some problem with GPS of your device. However code is working as it should have. Please go through the mentioned link in the answer to better understand the Working of location provider.